# полноэкранный режим для всех сезонов/серий

Tags: windows

На сайтах нахожу мультики с непрерывным воспроизведением (по типу сезон 1-99 серия 1-99)включаю полноэкранный режим после каждой серии переходит в оконный Есть ли способ оставить полноэкранный режим для всех сезонов/серий

Comment: Дайте ссылку для эксперимента.